# Couroutine onTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im working on a game that is like a rool a ball game, and now i have some doubts, i want to activate a event after enter a trigger, so after i enter my trigger i should wait like 2 seconds and then activate the event, the event is like changing the cameras so i pass a camera to false and the other to true, after that i want to wait more 2 seconds and go back, what i want is what some games have to, when you hit a button a door opens, so other camera is activated to see the door open and then it goes back to the player.

**I tried this**

```
public class button : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject elevator;
    private Camera second;
    void Start(){
        elevator = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        second = GameObject.Find("EventCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }


    IEnumerator WaitForSecs()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, 0.08f, transform.localPosition.z);
            transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            Camera.main.enabled = false;
            second.enabled = true;
            elevator.GetComponent<PingPong> ().enabled = true;
            Camera.main.enabled = true;
            second.enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that i don't know very well how to implement the coroutine in this case, i know how to do it on a update function, but here feels strange, need some help pls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked several times. Coroutines are not that complicated ;)

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, 0.08f, transform.localPosition.z);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        StartCoroutine( ShowDoor() ) ;
    }
}

IEnumerator ShowDoor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Camera.main.enabled = false;
    second.enabled = true;
    elevator.GetComponent<PingPong> ().enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Camera.main.enabled = true;
    second.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Little note : It's good practice to create only one `WaitForSeconds` and reuse it because creating it regularly takes some resources.

Comment: other thing i get a nullreferenceexception when i do the last 2 lines, i think it has something to do with the Camera.main.enabled,

Comment: Surely because you don't have a camera in your scene with the `MainCamera` tag?